# vue js toggle the function , based on ternary function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do i toggle the function I want to pass into @click event ?
This seems logical but does not work.

```
     <v-btn  @click="(this.name==='new') ? lookup: save" > <v-btn>
```

Comment: `@click="name === 'new' ? lookup() : save()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<v-btn  @click="functionToRun" > <v-btn>

methods : 
      functionToRun(){
      (this.name==='new') ? this.lookup(): this.save();
     }//end funtionToRun
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just creating a function which checks what the name is and calls a function from that instead of doing the check in the @click. Maybe, I haven't tried yet, it will work if you do `@click="() => { (this.name==='new') ? lookup() : save()};"` or just `@click="(this.name==='new') ? lookup() : save();"`, an arrow function is probably not needed.